# Estimating multiple interrelated parameters with mle2 (bbmle) and custom log likelihood function

Tags: r, mle, log-likelihood

To cut a long story short: I would like to estimate the parameter r of a utility function, which depends on demographic variables. I wrote a code for the utility function - that should be maximised -, transformed it into a log lik function and use it in mle2. I get a parameter estimate for r, but I do not get the parameters for the demographic variables.

Now the long story:

In specific, I want to estimate the parameter r in the following function:

```
CRRA <- function(x, r){
  u <- (x ^ (1-r)) / (1-r)
  return(u)
}
```

r describes risk attitude and I want to maximise utility u. r in turn depends on personal characteristics such that

```
r <- beta0 + beta1 * covar[1] + beta2 * covar[2] + beta3 * covar[3]
```

where the covars are known and I want to estimate beta0, beta1, ... , betaN and r.

I have choice data from different lottery games (multiple price lists) with 10 decision situations each. In each decision situation, the player needs to decide whether he/she wants to play lottery A or lottery B (choice data). A1, A2, B1 and B2 are the possible payoffs x and prob is the respective probability to receive the associated payoff. In lottery A the expected utility of a specific decision situation is

```
EU <- function(p, x, r){ #expected utility of one of the two lotteries in a pair
  eu <- p * CRRA(x[[1]], r) + (1-p) * CRRA(x[[2]], r) 
  return(eu)
}

EU(p = d[,("prob"), x = d[,("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2")], r)
```

The expected utility of the entire decision situation is

```
DELTA <- function(x, p, r){ #difference of lottery B (right, more risky) and lottery A (left, safe)
  delta <- EU(p, x[c(1,2)], r) - EU(p, x[c(3,4)], r)
  return(delta)
}
```

and depends on the choice variable. The choice variable is = 0 when lottery A is chosen and = 1 when lottery B is chosen.

Accordingly, the log likelihood function looks as follows:

```
Lc2 <- function(r){
    
  dl <- DELTA(x, prob, r)
  
  lc <- -sum(choice * pnorm(dl[1], log.p = TRUE) 
               (1 - choice) * pnorm(1 - dl[1], log.p = TRUE))
  return(lc)

}
```

Using Lc2 in mle2 provides the following results:

```
> fit2 <- mle2(Lc2,
+             data = df,
+             start = c(r=0.76),
+             parameters = list(r ~ age+ha+microbes))

> tidy(fit2)
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  term  estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 r        0.512    0.0445      11.5 1.21e-30

> summary(fit2)
Maximum likelihood estimation

Call:
mle2(minuslogl = Lc2, start = c(r = 0.76), data = df, parameters = list(r ~ 
    covar[1] + covar[2] + covar[3]))

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error z value     Pr(z)    
r 0.512122   0.044503  11.508 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

-2 log L: 743.4722
```

How do I get mle2 to calculate also parameter estimates for beta? Why does `parameter = list(r ~ covar[1] + covar[2] + covar[3])` inside `mle2` not provide me the beta estimates for each covar? Where do I need to place the `r <- ...` function?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help on this.

---

I tried the following:

```
U <- function(x, prob, params, covar){
  A1 <- x[1]
  A2 <- x[2]
  B1 <- x[3]
  B2 <- x[4]
  
  prob <- prob
  
  r <- params[1]
  beta0 <- params[2]
  beta1 <- params[3]
  beta2 <- params[4]
  beta3 <- params[5]
  
  
  r <- beta0 + beta1 * covar[1] + beta2 * covar[2] + beta3 * covar[3]
  
  u <- DELTA(x = c(A1, A2, B1, B2), prob = prob, r)
  return(u)
  }

loli <- function(params){
  
  d <- datan
  
  x <- d[,c("A1","A2","B1","B2")]
  prob <- d[,"prob"]
  covar <- d[,c("cov1", "cov2", "cov3")] %>% as.matrix(.)
  
  dl <- U(x = x, prob = prob, params = params, covar = covar)
  
  choice <- d[,"choice"]
  
  lc <- -sum(choice * pnorm(dl[[1]], log.p = TRUE) + 
                       (1 - choice) * pnorm(1 - dl[[1]], log.p = TRUE))
  
  return(lc)
}

guess <- list(params = c(0.76, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

... without success:

```
> fit3 <- mle2(loli, 
+              start = guess, 
+              data = choices_DL)
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “mle2” object: invalid object for slot "fullcoef" in class "mle2": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "numeric"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `parameters` works if you're not using the formula interface ... ?